# Between barbell and dumbbell?

Tags: dumbbells, weights, barbell, plates

I have a fitness tool which is somewhat between barbell and dumbbell.
I don't know what this is called.

It is a bar that is 60cm (24 inches) long and is supposed to hold a steel plate or plates to add weights.
It should be held by 'two hands' but is too short to be called 'barbell.'

What is this called?

Comment: 60cm is quite short short are you sure it's not a dumbbell? do you have pictures?

Comment: https://www.google.ee/search?q=ez+curl+bar&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUqOPUspPKAhXMliwKHfG-CBEQ_AUIBigB
something like this?

Comment: maybe [big boy bars](http://www.ironmind-store.com/images/1224-11_f.jpg) however you say they should be held by two hands these are clearly meant for one hand.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a short barbell. They're usually used for exercises like straight bar curls which require a barbell but not necessarily long ones since you don't have to use a rack like you would for squatting or pressing/bench pressing, and can be done without a wide grip.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 of these to use for dumbbell squats. It allows the weights to clear my knees going up and down. So the bar is a one handed thing.

Comment: But what is the name?

Comment: Post a photo. Is it home made?

Comment: You may have intended to post that comment to the main question...